# Can I colour cards in YouTrack AgileBoard?

Tags: agile, bug-tracking, youtrack

I'd like to colour the cards on my AgileBoard in YouTrack 6.0 by some custom rules. Anyone tried that? (eg to paint the whole Major Bug card in red).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In youtrack 6.0 you can use only single rule for cards coloring. It can be specified by "Field for color-coded cards" property in agile board settings where you can select it to be field or project based. In case of field based coloring for example 'Priority' field agile board will use colors of priorities of it's projects. For projects based coloring additional control 'Edit projects colors' will appear in agile board settings.

There is only one way to color the whole card. It is to select Minimal view. In all other cases only card headers will be colored.